# Designing Efficient memory for an Instruction Set Simulator

Tags: c++, c, memory, cpu-architecture, instruction-set

I'm designing an Instruction Set Simulator in C++, which is comprised of classes for the CPU, memory and the instruction set itself.  I am currently trying to design my memory class, which will consist of the `uint32_t` data type.

Basically the memory class would have to do the following:

1. Accept a value and an address and allocate that value to a particular address of the memory.
2. Get a value at a certain address. If something has been allocated to it before, get that value. Otherwise, return 0.

What comes to mind is that I require a search algorithm to find the address that I'm interested in.

I have already implemented the simplest version available, which would be a linear memory search, where the memory block in question would be just a simple struct, `*block` with a value and an address  stored in a `vector<block*>`. However, as you might guess, this is very expensive for large cases.

All in all, I would like to implement a case where memory can be easily found (I'm thinking binary search, but I'm open to more suggestions), and I would also like suggestions on arranging my memory block `*block`. I'm currently using a vector because I do not know the size of memory that I need.

Comment: How big is the memory you are trying to emulate? Typically when I have done this in the past, I have simply allocated the required amount of memory to allocate in a large block and then access it respectively.

Comment: There is no fixed size for the memory in question, as I am required to allocate memory on demand. For example, the test suite will ask for memory at locations 0x00000000, 0x0000000C, 0x0000200C, 0x40000000, 0x8000000C, 0xFFFFFFF0 in the same test file. However, there is a huge empty gap in between 0x80000010 and 0xFFFFFFEC and leaving this around would be quite inefficient because of the unused space. Appreciate the reply!

Answer (score 5):

You can create something similar as the way actual OS handle memory for processes. You can have *pages of memory* of, lets say, 64KB each, and store them in the following way:

Lets say your emulated application tried to store a `byte` at the address `0x05001234`.

That would be in memory page `0x0500` (1280 in decimal). You can simply read the first 16 bits to get the page address, a benefict of making it with exactly 64KB.

Use a `std::map` to keep your memory pages organized. Something like `std::map<int, char*> pages;`. Or an array `char *pages[0x00010000];` that should use 256KB of memory in 32-bit systems. Don't forget to zero it out.

Check if you already have a memory page `0x0500` in your set. You only have to see that `pages[0x0500]` is not `NULL`. If it is not there, `pages[0x0500] = new char[0x00010000];` to create it. Zero it out if you must.

Now just write the byte like `pages[0x0500][0x1234] = byte;`.

Comment: +1 Given OP's "design the entire class without any built-in functions" (by which I think he means Standard Library usage) - could have an array of `char*`.  Actual memory pages are likely to be ~4k on most commodity hardware, and with virtual addressing unaccessed regions of the arrays and pages won't require backing memory so it's all more efficient than it might sound....

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using std::map? That would do exactly what you are asking for. The address would be the key, and the value would be the data.

Comment: Hi Laszlo, thanks for the reply. Yup, I was thinking of using std::map but the specifications want me to design the entire class without any built-in functions, so I don't think that would be an option.